# Hardy space and boundary regularity

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis, hardy-spaces

Let $H^\infty(D)$ be the Hardy-space of bounded, holomorphic functions $\Phi:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, defined on the unit disk $D\subset \mathbb{C}$. It is a standard result that $\Phi\in H^\infty(D)$ has radial limits $\Phi^*(\omega)=\lim_{r\rightarrow 1}\Phi(r\omega)$ for almost every $\omega \in S^1=\partial D$.

**Questions.**

1. What can we say about the regularity of $\Phi^*\in L^\infty(S^1)$? What is the image of $H^\infty(D)$ under $\Phi\mapsto \Phi^*$ in $L^\infty(S^1)$?
2. More concretely: Is there an example where $\Phi^*$ is continuous away from a single point and with existing left/right limits at that point?

---

In an attempt to refute 2) I've considered functions $\Phi(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{S^1} \frac{\varphi(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d\zeta$, where $\varphi:S^1\backslash \{-1\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuously differentiable with existing (but possibly different) limits $a_\pm=\lim_{\theta\rightarrow \pm \pi}\varphi(e^{i\theta})$. I can show that$$
\Phi(-1+\epsilon)=\frac{(a_+-a_-)\ln\epsilon }{2\pi i} + \frac{a_++a_-}{2} - \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \psi(\theta) \log(e^{i\theta}+1-\epsilon) d\theta,
$$
where $\psi(\theta) = \frac{d}{d\theta} \varphi(e^{i\theta})$ and $\log$ is the principal branch of the logarithm. Given a supposed example as in 2), we could set $\varphi=\Phi^*$ and arrive at a contriction if the previous display blows up for $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. However, while the first term always blows up if $a_+\neq a_-$, it seems like this *could* in principle be cancelled by the integral (which can also blow up in the limit).

Comment: Basic theorem of Hardy space theory valid in $H^1$ actually, namely if the boundary function is of bounded variation, then it is continous and even much stronger, it is absolutely continuous; so nothing like in $2$ may exist; essentially the reason for continuity is that a circle function (bounded measurable or just integrable) is the ae radial limit of a holomorphic  function iff the negative Fourier coefficients  are zero, so the series for the real and imaginary  parts are conjugate Fourier sense, and that precludes jump discontinuities in either

Comment: Note that in the above comment the iff applies only to Hardy space theory so holomorphic functions that do not grow that fast (arbitrary highly unbounded holomorphic functions on the disc can have wild radial limits)

Comment: Thank you! It's indeed a theorem in paragraph 3.17 of Katznelson's harmonic analysis book - this had escaped my attention when I first checked.

Comment: Happy to be of help